# Error calling a Action Map

Tags: input, unreal-4, blueprints

**I tried calling the event Set Destination, simply to make an impression on the game screen:**

[image]

I did not succeed. I modified the 3 options displayed on the right (consume input / execute when paused / override parent binding), but nothing has changed the result.

Neither change the button that calls the event (from the right to the left or even the middle button).

**I created a new input (example):**

[image]

**And I was able to make the impression normally:**

[image]

Why can not I call the Set Destination?

I need to know a way to send a warning/signal (get reference) when this event is performed.

Comment: Is there a chance you might have bound RMB to the action "RightMouseButton" already? I am mentioning this, referring to the image for a question you asked 2 days prior.

Comment: @suvam0451 I did the test by changing the key just to avoid this. All 3 mappings have unique keys. Left, right and middle.